# Grub command line instead of menu

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, dual-boot

I have a problem with GRUB command line opening instead of grub menu. Surprisingly, when I type `exit` in the command line, the menu opens immediately.

I've had some adventures with Ubuntu:

1. I had windows installed on SSD A
2. Then installed Ubuntu on HDD B
3. Added a new SSD C and installed Ubuntu there. By mistake, I chose bootloader device to the SSD C, instead of SSD A.

Since then, I've had the described problem with grub commandline.

Trying to fix it, I've formatted all Linux partitions, as well as Windows' boot partition and then recovered it with Windows' `bootrec` tool. Then installed Ubuntu again, but the problem still occurs. How can I fix it, or at least troubleshoot it?

Info from `gdisk -l`:

```
$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda 
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          923647   450.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   2          923648         1185791   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   3         1185792       468875263   223.0 GiB   0700  Basic data partition

$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048        48001023   22.9 GiB    8200  
   2        48001024       176001023   61.0 GiB    8300  
   3       176001024       512002047   160.2 GiB   8300

$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      1953521663   931.5 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
```

Contents of `/boot/efi`:

```
➜  ~ sudo ls -la /boot/efi   
total 12
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 sty  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 lis 28 18:58 ..
drwx------ 5 root root 4096 lis 28 18:52 EFI
```

Comment: Are you using EFI style booting or legacy BIOS booting?

Comment: I'm using UEFI.

Comment: Can you show `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdx` for all three disks? I suspect there is more than one EFI System Partition in your system and the UEFI is configured to boot one of the obsolete GRUB installations.

Comment: @Hermann :
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          923647   450.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   2          923648         1185791   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   3         1185792       468875263   223.0 GiB   0700  Basic data partition

Comment: That seems to be only one of the disks involved. Editing the question and adding the information in code markup would help readability. In the meantime: If you bring up the boot selection menu during system start and select the correct disk, does GRUB work right away?

Comment: You have only one ESP. That is looking good so far. Can you check if there is more than one `.efi` file in `/boot/EFI`?